# Qt Multiple Line Text In Custom Delegate

Tags: c++, ruby, qt

I have a custom delegate derived from QStyleOptionViewItem which is trying to draw multiline (wordwrap) a long line of text in the paint method. After doing some search and Qt doc reading, I looks like I need to use QTextLayout for such task, below is the code I have which still puts the text in one single line, any hints on how to wrapping the line around length of the QStyleOptionViewItem passed in? Thanks!!

```
void Delegate::paint(QPainter *painter,
                     const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                     const QModelIndex &index) const
{
  painter->save();

  painter->translate(option.rect.topLeft());

  QString title = index.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
  QTextLayout * layout = new QTextLayout(title, QApplication::font());

  layout->beginLayout();
  QTextLine line = layout->createLine();
  while (line.isValid()) {
    line.setLineWidth(option.rect.width());
    line = layout->createLine();
  }
 layout->endLayout();
  layout->draw(painter, QPointF(0, 0));

  painter->restore();
}
```

Since I can't self answer, I will just post my findings here.
I found couple issues with my code:

1. The test string I are one word consisted of 200 characters and by default QTextLayout does word wrap. So I have to explicitly call QTextLayout::setWrapMode() for that test case to wrap.
2. I am not setting position for each line.

This is my paint method in Ruby:

```
def paint painter, styleOptionViewItem, modelIndex
  painter.save
  painter.translate styleOptionViewItem.rect.top_left

  marked_text = modelIndex.data(Qt::DisplayRole).value
  font = Qt::Application::font()
  text_layout = Qt::TextLayout.new marked_text
  text_layout.setFont font

  text_option = Qt::TextOption.new
  text_option.setWrapMode(Qt::TextOption::WrapAtWordBoundaryOrAnywhere)
  text_layout.setTextOption text_option

  text_layout.beginLayout
  fm = Qt::FontMetrics.new font
  font_height = fm.height
  i = 0
  while i< LINE_LIMIT do
    line = text_layout.createLine
    break if (!line.isValid())
    line.setLineWidth(styleOptionViewItem.rect.width)
    line.setPosition(Qt::PointF.new(0, font_height * i))
    i += 1
  end
  text_layout.endLayout
  text_layout.draw painter, Qt::PointF.new(0, 0)
  painter.restore
end
```

Comment: This [PySide Page](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QTextLayout.html) under "Detailed Description" has the code I am trying to mimic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to do same task for a while.
While I used simple [`QPainter::drwText`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#drawText-11), I bumped into this issue.

To make word wrap work, you should:

- disable `uniformRowHeight` property of view.
- handle [`sizeHint`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qitemdelegate.html#sizeHint) correctly. By default this function return `0`, you should override it to return `Qt::SizeHint` role of item data.
- But you should also set correct value for `Qt::SizeHint` role. You can use [`QFontMetrics::boundingRect`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qfontmetrics.html#boundingRect-6) to calculate `sizeHint`, but you should ensure you use *same font* when calculating `sizeHint` and when drawing item. On `Windows 7` I had an issue, that font of `QStandardItem` didn't coincide with `QListView`'s one.

  Note, that it is bad idea to calculate `sizeHint` from scratch every time it requested, because it works really slow.